# How to set No of output file per reducer in Custom Partitioner Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have implemented custom partition based on my logic .and i am able to get files also properly .But because of the condition some of the reducer is having very huge data and that leads to delay in reducer phase.

So is there any way so that i can create many small files inside one reducer output file .

Here is my custom partioner

```
public class MyPartioner extends Partitioner<Text, IntWritable> {
  public int getPartition(Text key, IntWritable value, int setNumRedTask) {
   String str = key.toString();
   if (str.contains("Japan|2014")) {
    return 0;
   } else if (str.contains("Japan|2013")) {
    return 1;
   }  else if (str.contains("Japan|2012")) {
    return 2;
   } else if (str.contains("Japan|2011")) {
    return 3;
   } else
    return 4;
  }
```

First condition have very huge amount of data like 20 GB but last will have 12 mb .

Answer (score 0):

Your input set has a lot of records having "Japan|2014".

Simplest way would be to add "Japan|{month}|2014" or use multi-outputs to achieve the same.

Comment: Yes i can use MultiOutput but then it will create more number of files because i am reading records from HBase that has 200 regions and so it will create 200 output files .But in my case I need one output file for Japan?2014.